# Display none div shows white spaces in slick slider

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have two problems in the slider. I need to hide and show images based on selection of color selection by client i.e if user select red color all corresponding red images would if white than all corresponding white images would show based on selection.[image]

1. Now the first problem is in the above image in the slider white space shows of the display none elements even if the red selections show

[image]

2. Thumbnail slider also shows white spaces and the position of the thumbnail also changes.

Here are the javascripts of slick slider

```
function slideProductDetail() {
    $('.js_prod_main').slick({
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      arrows: false,
      dot: false,
      fade: false,
      infinite: false,
      asNavFor: '.js_prod_sub'
    });
    $('.js_prod_sub').slick({
      slidesToShow: 5,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      //asNavFor: '.js_prod_main',
      dots: false,
      arrows: false,
      infinite: false,
      vertical: true,
      verticalSwiping: true,
      focusOnSelect: true,
      responsive: [
        {
          breakpoint: 1200,
          settings: {
            vertical: true,
            infinite: false,
          }
        },
        {
          breakpoint: 768,
          settings: {
            vertical: true,
            infinite: false,
          }
        },
        
        {
          breakpoint: 575,
          settings: {
            vertical: false,
            infinite: false,
          }
        }
      ]
    });
  
   }
```

I have all images set of images(both white and red images) in shopify if the user select color red set of red colour images would show in slider and white then only white colour. The images of display none div shows white empty spaces

Comment: Have you checked out the ability to *filter* elements in Slick Slider?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier do you have references I have tried a lot, actually I have all images set of images(both white and red images) in shopify if the user select color red set of red colour images would show in slider and white then only white colour. The images of display none div shows white empty spaces

Comment: Sure, [here's the example page of Slick Slider](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/). Look for the filter section. The example there uses a pseudo selector to filter the even and uneven elements, but using a class like `'.white'` should also work.

Comment: But if you still need help with it then include the JS where you show / hide the elements currently.